# HTML elements gets scrambled when the user clicks the maximize button

Tags: html, css

I am creating a very simple webpage to position elements inside the body tag I use:

```
<div style="position:relative;left:12px;top:50px;">
    <b>No account yet?</b>
    ...
</div>
    <div style="position:relative;left:127px;top:40px;">
    ...
</div>
```

When the browser is maximized positions are fine, but when the user resize his/her browser it gets scrambled. Any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by scrambled? Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Using `position` to lay out elements is an inflexible method of website layout. There are **much** better and responsive layout methods - See [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `float: left;` and position it with `margin: top right bottom left`

similar to this:

```
<div style="float: left; margin: 50px 0 0 12px;">
<b>No account yet?</b>
...
</div>
<div style="float: left; margin: 40px 0 0 127px;">
...
</div>
```

Comment: This is what i meant that when the browser resized to small the elements scrambled http://i.imgur.com/Q7Tmi4b.png